# Can't create directory on external storage when targetsdkversion = 30

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to create a directory in Downloads folder to store downloaded files from my apk. In Android 11 it was successful when targetsdkversion was less than 30 but when I make targetsdkversion = 30 in build.gradle, I can neither create directory nor list files inside any folder.

```
Directory temp = await getExternalStorageDirectory();

String savedPath = '${temp.parent.parent.parent.parent.path}/Download/Short Videos';


\\ Here savedPath = /storage/emulated/0/Download/Short Videos

if (!Directory(savedPath).existsSync()) {
      Directory(savedPath).createSync();
    }
```

What changes should I make to androidmanifest.xml and app level build.grade so that directory on external storage can be created and files can be listed inside a directory?

Answer (score 0):

From Android 11 (API level 30) several restriction has been added on accessing external storage. Apps that run on Android 11 but target Android 10 (API level 29) can still request the requestLegacyExternalStorage attribute. This flag allows apps to temporarily opt out of the changes associated with scoped storage, such as granting access to different directories and different types of media files. After you update your app to target Android 11, the system ignores the requestLegacyExternalStorage flag.

**getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDir("");** will give you your app's specific external storage directory and no other apps will be able to access its contents.